# How to install Scala support in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, eclipse-neon

How can I add Scala support to Eclipse Neon?

The [Scala Documentation Getting Started](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html) page does not even describe how to install Scala at all much less how to integrate it with Neon.

Comment: Have you tried to install [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org) via the [Eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide)?

Answer (score 6):

We have Scala plugin for the Eclipse. In the eclipse, Go to Help -> Install New Software and click on Add Button providing the 
**Name: Scala**

**URL: http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site**

Click on Ok Button and then it will display the list of all components.Select the component Scala IDE for Eclipse and then click on Finish Button and then restart eclipse.This will add the Scala Plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: Doesn't Work anymore??

Comment: I am also unable to download scala ide. The link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Download Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/scala2.html) (Scala 2) page,

1. First, make sure you have the Java 8 JDK (or Java 11 JDK) installed.
2. Then, install Scala... either by installing an IDE such as IntelliJ, or sbt, Scala's build tool.

This is confusing for beginners because you don't download Scala explicitly.

> Compared to other programming languages, installing Scala is a bit unusual. Scala is unusual because it is usually installed for each of your Scala projects rather than being installed system-wide.

As for the IDE, the official Scala download page recommends IntelliJ. It has seamless integration with sbt.
However, if you want to use Eclipse, get the Scala plugin from http://scala-ide.org/.

See [Scala - Getting Started](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/scala-getting-started/) for details with an example, including setting up IntelliJ and Eclipse.